# How does External HDD with NTFS format works on Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, file-format

I connected my external HDD which is formatted in NTFS file format,
I was able to read as well as write to it.

I have read that Linux can only read NTFS drives but can't write to them.
How does this work?

P.S
Will my HDD get corrupt if I connect it back to Windows system?

Comment: Ubuntu normally reads & writes to NTFS partitions without issue. But when NTFS needs repairs, you have to use Windows to run chkdsk or defrag it. And newer Windows 8 or 10 has fast start up which will set a hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. Then Linux will not write to it to prevent damage. Make sure fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred What about Winodws 7 that does not provide "fast startup feature"?

Comment: As long as you do not hibernate, it should work without issue. When dual booting we still suggest a shared NTFS data partition for any data you may want in both systems. Best not to set main Windows system, the c: drive, as read/write but as read only if you want access to it from Ubuntu. And use NTFS data partition as read/write partition. But still best with Ubuntu to use Linux formats like ext4 for most of your Linux data.

Comment: I agree with @oldfred. Ubuntu can read/write to NTFS HDD as long as the file system is clean. To permanently share files between Windows and Ubuntu, create a shared NTFS partition (do not use your C: drive for this).

Comment: @oldfred thnx. for solving this query and for sharing a nice tip.

P.S
The file system works by pointing the cluster of data in the drive and making a table of cluster start node and the reference pointer. The Windows must does this in the files which we cant see in Windows but we can see them in Linux.

So if Linux is writing or reading the data from this file without updating the pointer reference table how could Windows know where are the need files located on the disk.

As removing those windows file makes are drive useless if you plug them back into the Windows OS.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you too for helping me out. Could you also share your insights on my previous comment, that would be helpful :)

Comment: It's much simpler than all that. Windows can do some funny things to NTFS that Linux doesn't know how to handle... and manipulating the C: drive from Linux can cause Windows some grief. That's the reason you use a separate NTFS partition or external NTFS HDD to share/transfer files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read and write NTFS in Ubuntu and you can connect your external HDD in Windows and it will not be a problem.
To see how this works you can visit [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions#NTFS).